# Parallel Ajax Requests in Jquery With Progress Bar

Tags: jquery, progress-bar

Depending upon user action, i need to make ajax calls ranging from one call to three parallel calls. I want to show Progress bar for that as well. One Progress bar for any number of Ajax Requests. Following is the sample code i am going to tweak. Can anyone suggest how can i limit the number of calls and how ONE progress bar can be used for this.

```
  $.when(
 // Get the HTML
  $.get("/feature/", function(html) {
  globalStore.html = html;
 }),

 // Get the CSS
 $.get("/assets/feature.css", function(css) {
globalStore.css = css;
 }),

 // Get the JS
 $.getScript("/assets/feature.js")

 ).then(function() {

  // All is ready now, so...

  // Add CSS to page
     $("<style />").html(globalStore.css).appendTo("head");

     // Add HTML to page
   $("body").append(globalStore.html);

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

jQuery $.when() and $.done() are exactly what you need:

$.when($.ajax("/page1.php"), $.ajax("/page2.php"))
  .then(myFunc, myFailure);

Answer (score 0):

other wise you can try this
you could do something like this

> var allData = [] $.getJSON("/values/1", function(data) {
>       allData.push(data);
>       if(data.length == 2){
>         processData(allData) // where process data processes all the data
>       } });
>
> $.getJSON("/values/2", function(data) {
>       allData.push(data);
>       if(data.length == 2){
>         processData(allData) // where process data processes all the data
>       } });
>
> var processData = function(data){
>        var sum = data[0] + data[1]
>        $('#mynode').html(sum); }

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
  var ajax1 = function(){jQuery.ajax({......})};
  var ajax2 = function(){jQuery.ajax({......}};
  function loadMultipleAjax(){
                               //add loading statement
                             jQuery.when(ajax1,ajax2)
                             .done(function(){
                                //remove loading statement
                           })};


 //call 
loadMultipleAjax();
```